# Get Email Alert When Someone logins to Computer/Server locally or remotely

Tags: vbscript

I have a script when runs sends an email notification with attached logs but only time and date don't know where i am wrong it should be sending username who logged in, computer name, IP, client name & session.

If its possible to logs generated but attached in the body of email not as output attachment

Here is the script:

```
On Error Resume Next

'Define the Update AD attribute and define all variables
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2
Dim objSysInfo, objNetwork, strCompName, strUserDN, objUser, strClientName, strTerminalServerIdent

'Part of the computer name that is unique to terminal servers (e.g. XYZ-TS-00X) must be lower case.
strTerminalServerIdent = "-ts-"

'Create the objects required to get required information
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

'Set the variables required
strCompName = LCase(objNetwork.ComputerName)
strUserDN = objSysInfo.userName

'check if the computer name is a Terminal Server
If Instr(strCompName,strTerminalServerIdent) > 0 then
  strClientName = clientName()
  If strClientName <> "" then
    strCompName = trim(strClientName)
  End If
End If

'Connect to the user/computer AD path (Bind)
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)

'Add the computer name to the Office AD value for the user and save it
objUser.Put"physicalDeliveryOfficeName", Trim(Ucase(strCompName))
objUser.SetInfo

'Close/empty all the variables (tidy up)
strCompName = ""
strCompName = Null

strUserDN = ""
strUserDN = Null

strClientName = ""
strClientName = Null

Set objSysInfo = Nothing
Set objNetwork = Nothing
Set objUser = Nothing

'############# FUNCTIONS REQUIRED #########################
Function sessionNumber()
  Dim oShell, oExec, sOutput, iUserPos, iUserLen, iStatePos
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set oExec = oShell.Exec("query session %username%")
  sOutput = LCase(oExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
  iUserPos = InStr(sOutput,LCase(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")))
  iStatePos = InStr(sOutput,"active")
  iUserLen = Len(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%"))
  sessionNumber = CInt(Trim(Mid(sOutput,iUserPos+iUserLen,iStatePos-iUserPos-iUserLen)))
End Function

Function clientName()
  Dim oShell
  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  On Error Resume Next
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    clientName = LCase(oShell.RegRead("HKCU\Volatile Environment\"& sessionNumber() &"\CLIENTNAME"))
  Else
    clientName =  ""
  End If
End Function

outFile="C:\batch\logged.txt"

Const ForAppending = 8

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile(outFile,ForAppending,True)
objFile.Write now() & " ; " & clientName & " " & clientIP & vbCrLf
objFile.Close

Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

emailObj.From     = "*****"
emailObj.To       = "*****"
emailObj.Subject  = "Login Alerts"
emailObj.TextBody = "See the attched login information"
emailObj.AddAttachment "C:\batch\logged.txt"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("*"
emailConfig.Fields("*") = 25
emailConfig.Fields("*")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("")    = "***"
emailConfig.Fields("")    = "****"

emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a client name for local logins, that's just how it is. And you use `clientIP` without defining a function or variable elsewhere in your code so it's automatically initialized as an empty variable. Use `Option Explicit` to get warnings about uninitialized variables.

On a more general note, do NOT use global `On Error Resume Next` in your code. Ever. Contrary to popular belief it doesn't magically make errors go away. The only thing it ever does is making your code fail silently in unexpected places, leaving you none the wiser.

Comment: It would be great if you can just mention all the steps or paste the complete code so that i can copy and paste

Comment: That is not going to happen.

Comment: @ I Wasnt asking you BDW I was asking Sujith

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fso, content, lines
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set content = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\batch\logged.txt",1)
lines = content.ReadAll
objMessage.TextBody = lines
```

The above will help you paste the contents of the output file into the body of the mail instead of attachment.

It would be better If use split up the script into 2 seperate scripts and call them using a batch file with a delay between them.

Comment: Now it wont send email, on my office network with office smtp, it works on my email